# How to return substring positions in LIKE query

Tags: mysql, position, sql-like

I retrieve data from a MySQL database using a simple SELECT FROM WHERE LIKE case-insensitive query where I escape any `%` or `_` in the like clause, so really the user can only perform basic text research and cannot mess up with regex because I then surround it myself with `%` in the LIKE clause.

For every row returned by this query, I have to search again using a JS script in order to find all the indexes of the substring in the original string. I dislike this method because I it's a different pattern matching than the one used by the LIKE query, I can't guarantee that the algorithm is the same.

I found MySQL functions `POSITION` or `LOCATE` that can achieve it, but they return only the first index if it was found or 0 if it was not found. Yes you can set the first index to search from, and by searching by passing the previously returned index as the first index until the new returned index is 0, you can find all indexes of the substring, but it means a lot of additional queries and it might end up slowing down my application a lot.

So I'm now wondering: ***Is there a way to have the `LIKE` query to return substring positions*** directly, but I didn't find any because I lack MySQL vocabulary yet (I'm a noob).

Comment: "Regex" is not what is used in "LIKE".  Are you talking about "RLIKE" (aka "REGEX"); if not, please avoid using "regex".

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055). Data example must contain all possible variations.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:  No.

Longer answer:  MySQL has no syntax or mechanism ot return an array of anything -- from either a `SELECT` or even a Stored Procedure.

Maybe answer:  You could write a Stored procedure that loops through one result, finding the results and packing them into a commalist.  But I cringe at how messy that code would be.  I would quickly decide to write JS code, as you have already done.

Moral of the story:  SQL is is not a full language.  It's great at storing and efficiently retrieving large sets of *rows*, but lousy at string manipulation or arrays (other than "rows").

**Commalist**

If you are actually searching a simple list of things separated by commas, then `FIND_IN_SET()` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` in MySQL closely match what JS can be done with its split (on comma) method on strings.

Comment: Since I'm using LIKE I'm concerned about my JS indexOf function because I want it to behave exactly like the MySQL LIKE function, and I don't know what's behind it except that It's UTF8 Unicode and that the collation ignores case when comparing string. Should I then just write a JS function finding indexes of a lower-cased substring inside a lower-cased string?

Comment: Give us some specifics on what type of things you might be searching for with LIKE.  (See my added comments on "commalist".)